# Am I a bad intern? Pls tell me

Tags: internship

Ok so here is the thing. I'm currently doing an  internship (for school) with one of my friends and our colleagues are her brother, his best friend and a family friend.

- no matter what I do there is always something wrong with it. Even when I did the same thing before and everything was fine at first.*
- I always get told to talk more. Its not like I don't talk it's just that talking makes me feel uncomfortable, idk why but it's always been like this.
- I feel like one of our colleagues does not like me or treats me different than my friend. Ok so here is the thing it's the same thing as *  and it's just that he always no matter how hard I try something wrong with what I do. And he always tells me to be faster but I just can't at the moment I've injured my wrist before the internship started and it's just hurting a lot.

Comment: What is the nature of your internship, is it physical activity or office work?
Is there consequences if you fail your internship?

Comment: All interns feel like that, you're new, you're learning! The point of an internship is that you learn what it's like to be in that environment

Comment: Hi Salima, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question is too broad to provide a single answer as it is. It will be closed, but you can [edit] it and provide more information, so it can be reopened. First of all, we need a goal. What would you like to achieve? Because we can't tell you if you're a bad intern (although you're most likely not). We can help you figure out how to ask for help at work or how to deal with a colleague that treats you differently than your friend or how to figure out if there is anything wrong with your work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know both the sides of the story- so I can't arrive at any conclusion, however, don't assume malice and always expect good intentions. I'll try to clarify some points:

> *no matter what I do there is always something wrong with it. Even when I did the same thing before and everything was fine at first.*

**Q:** Is it possible that the supervisors are trying to make you better at work?

Hint: Maybe they are not finding faults, rather, letting you know of the difference of the institutional education vs industry work. Maybe they are nitpicking, but with a good intention to raise the level of work produced and delivered by you.

> I always get told to talk more. Its not like I don't talk it's just that talking makes me feel uncomfortable, idk why but it's always been like this.

**Q:** Is it possible that they are trying to teach you the value of communication/ expressing yourself?

Hint: Knowing something is good, but unless you can communicate properly, most of it will render useless.

> *I feel like one of our colleagues does not like me or treats me different than my friend. Ok so here is the thing it's the same thing as * and it's just that he always no matter how hard I try something wrong with what I do. And he always tells me to be faster but I just can't at the moment I've injured my wrist before the internship started and it's just hurting a lot.*

**Q:** Is it possible they are trying to get you out of your comfort zone, and helping you learn to push your limits?

Hint: OK, I get that working with an injured wrist is a real problem - question is do they know about your problem? Did you tell them already?

- If you did not tell them already, how are they supposed to know? Go ahead and mention you are not slowing up because of laziness or something, you have a physical injury. I'm sure they'll understand.
- If you told them, and still they ignored the problem and keeps pushing - well, do your best and let them know that without hurting yourself, that's the limit you can reach. There's no harm in knowing one's limit **and** most importantly, learning to say **no**.

If you see carefully, the answer to all above questions is yes, it's very much possible.

So I'd say, neither you are a bad intern, nor you have bad mentors, try to keep an open mind and hopefully you'll start to understand and enjoy the work and the atmosphere.

*P.S - Even if I'm blatantly wrong in my assumptions, remember, the best lessons are sometimes learnt from the worst experiences. Whatever happens, keep the learning, let go the past and move on.*

Comment: They do know about my injured wrist already.